# Some $2\times 2$ real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Suppose $A$ a real matrix of dimension $2$,  having two not real conjugate eigenvalues. I want to prove if $B$ is another real $2\times 2$ matrix commuting with $A$,  then the eigenvalues of $B$ are conjugate (same norm).

Maybe the proof relies on a manipulation of entries $a_{i,j}$ and $b_{i,j}$ but the conditions are not easy to extract.
Thanks for ideas.

Comment: It would be a good question *if* you add some of your own thoughts to the problem.

Comment: False take any diagonal matrix $B$ iwth distinct real values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ has conjugate eigenvalues then it has in some basis a representation $PAP^{-1}=A_a=\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} $.

Let $B_a$ be any matrix $\begin{bmatrix} c & d \\ e & f \end{bmatrix} $ which is commutative with $A_a$ in this basis

i.e. $A_aB_a=B_aA_a$.

Compare 
$\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} c & d \\ e & f \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} c & d \\ e & f \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$

and you should obtain conditions for $c,d,e,f$

If the representation is of the form like $A_a$  ( $c=f$ and $d=-e$) then you'll achieve the desired result because eigenvalues are constant under  a change of basis (so their property of conjugation) and commutation for both matrices holds also under a change of basis.